# wordpress gutenberg change style of columns block based props

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

I don't like the behavior of the wordpress columns block and wanted to extend it by adding attributes. I can already do that part but I don't know how I change the styles of each columns, especially the width. There is a default range slider where you can set the width of the block in %. I want to do the same but with my own preset values. How do I do that?

Edit: I managed to achive what I was trying to do. I created a custom block with inner child blocks. Each child wrapper has the clientid of the child as html attribute id. So I can use JS to select and change its attributes but it feels kind of dirty. I guess there is still a react/jsx or "proper" way of doing that which I want to know.

Here a image of how it looks like now
[image]

Comment: can you show the image where you want to extend the width in wordpress gutenberg ?

Comment: I did update my post